# Enable NVIDIA VGA in Google GCP Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nvidia, vulkan, vga

Hi I created a Google Compute Engine with Tesla T4 GPU. I want to be able to run some application that renders some graphics. So i need NVIDIA GPU for display.

OS : Ubuntu 18.04

I tried installing the NVIDIA proprietary drivers , still i am unable to see any valid NVIDIA VGA Device.

But the compute instance i created doesn't seem to be exposing the VGA driver for NVIDIA. 
when i do lshw -c display , it only shows Nvidia as a 3D accelerator and not as VGA Compatible device.

Hence my doubt, how do i enable VGA capability for NVIDA Card on Google Cloud Compute Platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google supports virtual display devices only on Windows instances that use any Windows images or higher.

Virtual display devices are not compatible with instances running the Sandy Bridge CPU platform.

Here are the instructions to [enable a Virtual Display in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-instance-virtual-display) instances

Comment: yep that seems to be the case for GCP + Nvidia + Windows Combination. With Windows i was able to see Nvidia showiing up as a display adapter. But GCP + Ubuntu 18 + Nvidia T4 --> the NVidia T4 doesnt act as Display Driver , but only for computation i believe. I tried the official Nvidia Quadro Virtual Workstation Image on Ubuntu -- still dont have any luck in getting the Video driver to work with Nvidia.